# How to find out what open sessions my servlet based application is handling at any given moment

Tags: servlets, httpsession, session-management

I need to write a servlet that, when called, gets information about a list of the currently opened sessions.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement [`HttpSessionListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html), give it a `static Set<HttpSession>` property, add the session to it during `sessionCreated()` method, remove the session from it during `sessionDestroyed()` method, register the listener as `<listener>` in `web.xml`. Now you've a class which has all open sessions in the current JBoss instance collected. Here's a basic example:

```
public HttpSessionCollector implements HttpSessionListener {
    private static final Set<HttpSession> sessions = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        sessions.add(event.getSession());
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        sessions.remove(event.getSession());
    }

    public static Set<HttpSession> getSessions() {
        return sessions;
    }
}
```

Then in your servlet just do:

```
Set<HttpSession> sessions = HttpSessionCollector.getSessions();
```

If you rather want to store/get it in the application scope so that you can make the `Set<HttpSession>` **non-static**, then let the `HttpSessionCollector` implement [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) *as well* and add basically the following methods:

```
public void contextCreated(ServletContextEvent event) {
    event.getServletContext().setAttribute("HttpSessionCollector.instance", this);
}

public static HttpSessionCollector getCurrentInstance(ServletContext context) {
    return (HttpSessionCollector) context.getAttribute("HttpSessionCollector.instance");
}
```

which you can use in Servlet as follows:

```
HttpSessionCollector collector = HttpSessionCollector.getCurrentInstance(getServletContext());
Set<HttpSession> sessions = collector.getSessions();
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps using a JMX bean is more elegant and needs no code. Just read the value of

data: jboss.web:type=Manager,path=/myapplication,host=localhost" activeSessions