# Inject HttpSessionListener in OncePerRequestFilter

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-security, spring-boot

**How does one correctly inject a class that summarizes the currently active sessions into a custom `OncePerRequestFilter`?**

When I try to inject the following `HttpSessionCollector` into my custom filter, the result is a `NullPointerException` shown in the stack trace at bottom:

```
public class HttpSessionCollector implements HttpSessionListener, ServletContextListener {

    private static final Set<HttpSession> sessions = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        sessions.add(event.getSession());
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        sessions.remove(event.getSession());
    }

    public static Set<HttpSession> getSessions() {
        return sessions;
    }

    public void contextCreated(ServletContextEvent event) {
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("HttpSessionCollector.instance", this);
    }

    public static HttpSessionCollector getCurrentInstance(ServletContext context) {
        return (HttpSessionCollector) context.getAttribute("HttpSessionCollector.instance");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

The code for `DiagnoseSessionsFilter` that is failing to inject the `HttpSessionCollector` is:

```
@Component
public class DiagnoseSessionFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter implements ServletContextAware {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain fc)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("...........///////////// START OF DiagnoseSessionFilter.doFilterInternal() ///////////...........");
        HttpSessionCollector collector = HttpSessionCollector.getCurrentInstance(getServletContext());
        Set<HttpSession> sessions = collector.getSessions();

        System.out.println("sessions.size() is: " + sessions.size());
        for(HttpSession sess : sessions){
            System.out.println("sess is: " + sess);
            System.out.println("sess.getId() is: " + sess.getId());
        }

        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        System.out.println("...........///////////// END OF DiagnoseSessionFilter.doFilterInternal() ///////////...........");
        fc.doFilter(req, res);

    }
}
```

The `DiagnoseSessionsFilter` is injected into the Spring Security Filter Chain using the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in the following code excerpt from the main application class.  However, this level of the Filter injection might not be relevant to the OP because the `DiagnoseSessionsFilter` is indeed running at the right point in the filter chain.  The problem is with the injection of `HttpSessionCollector` into the `DiagnoseSessionsFilter`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("attrName")
@EnableResourceServer
public class NameOfApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NameOfApplication.class, args);
    }

    //lots of other stuff

    @Bean
    public static DiagnoseSessionFilter diagnoseSessionFilter(){
        return new DiagnoseSessionFilter();
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(-20)
    protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
             .addFilterBefore(diagnoseSessionFilter(), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
             .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
             .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/url/pattern").permitAll()
             .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/another/url/pattern").permitAll()
             .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

    }

    //other stuff
}
```

The stack trace of the error is:

```
...........///////////// START OF DiagnoseSessionFilter.doFilterInternal() ///////////...........
2016-06-05 14:53:24.572 ERROR 5941 --- [nio-9999-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/uaa] threw exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at examine.HttpSessionCollector.getCurrentInstance(HttpSessionCollector.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at demo.DiagnoseSessionFilter.doFilterInternal(DiagnoseSessionFilter.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Note: The approach in this OP is modified from [@BalusC's answer to this other question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113662/how-to-find-out-what-open-sessions-my-servlet-based-application-is-handling-at-a#2114150)